# Find key in map of List (Set) by one of List (Set) values

Tags: list, dart, dictionary, search, set

In `Map<String, Set<Type>>` I want to find key which contains Set which contains given Type (Value of Set).

Have:

```dart
final map = <String, Set<Type>>{
  'key1': <Type>{
    Type1,
    Type2,
  },
  'key2': <Type>{
    Type3,
    Type4,
  },
}
```

Want:

```dart
find(map, Type3); // 'key2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Map#entries](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/entries.html) with [`firstWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) (or [`firstWhereOrNull`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/firstWhereOrNull.html) from [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection))

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

typedef Type1 = int;
typedef Type2 = double;
typedef Type3 = String;
typedef Type4 = Object;

void main() {
  final map = <String, Set<Type>>{
    'key1': <Type>{
      Type1,
      Type2,
    },
    'key2': <Type>{
      Type3,
      Type4,
    },
  };

  final search = Type3;
  print(
    map.entries.firstWhereOrNull(
      (entry) => entry.value.contains(search),
    )?.key,
  );
}
```